# EF 5 cast a ICollection into another

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a component that accept two types as datasource

```
public interface Ia
{
    ....

    ICollection<Ib> Detail{ get; set; }
}

public interface Ib
{
    ....
}
```

Then I have two EF classes that implements the interfaces

```
public class b:Ib
{
}
```

And here is my problem. How to cast MyDetail to Detail and Detail to MyDetail, I'm trying to use Detail to encapsulate MyDetail

```
public class a : Ia
{
    public virtual ICollection<b> MyDetail{get;set;}
    // How to cast MyDetal to Detail and Detail to MyDetail
    // Something like 

    public virtual ICollection<Ib> Detail
    {
       get {return MyDetail;}
       set {MyDetail =  value;}     
    }

}
```

Is this posible? there is another aproach to perform this conversión ?

Comment: don't you just do `(IList<a>)ICollection<Ib>`

Comment: Tks for your help, could you show me that in a code simple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.  `ICollection` is not covariant, so you cannot treat a `ICollection<b>` as a `ICollection<Ib>` (in the getter), and its not contravariant, so you can't treat a `ICollection<Ib>` as a `ICollection<b>` (in the setter).  `ICollection<T>` is *invariant*.  (Note that it's impossible for anything to ever be both contravariant and covariant.

For your getter the best that you could do is create a new collection and copy over all of the elements.  You know it will succeed, but you do need to make the copy.

For your setter you would also need to make a new collection, but here you have no idea of all of the items actually are `b` objects, so you need to know how to handle any that aren't (do you omit them, throw an exception, or what).

Comment: Tks for your heñp. I found something that would help me, but it is incomplete It hasn't the setter. What do you think about it ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555028/implementing-an-icollectionisomething-with-a-concrete-type-to-satisfy-entity-f?rq=1)

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez IEnumerable is covariant.  It is not contravariant, so it will work as a getter, but not a setter.  If you only need to iterate the results, and not use any of the actions only found in `ICollection`, nor do you need to set it, then that sounds like the best option.  Of course, that's a lot of additional constraints that I have no idea if you can live with, which is why I couldn't suggest it in an answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about it. What Kind of constraints? some samples of them ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Whether or not you need a setter, whether or not you need to add items to the object returned from this property, or access its count, or know that it represents materialized items rather than a query of items, etc.

Comment: That sounds like It isn't a solution for me. Very very tks for your help.